# excluding parent dependencies when running sonar analysis

Tags: maven, sonarqube, nexus, nexus3

I am trying to use sonarQube on a Nexus Repository Plugin.

When creating a simple maven-project and calling

```
sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.scm.provider=git \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=de.zeb:sonartest \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.login=6cb308c50e4fc2af070777e44323061b1ed8c311
```

the build succedes and i can see the sonar result on the docker container i created.

But when adding the needed parent-pom to create nexus-plugins: ([https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/bundle-development/bundle-development-overview](https://pastebin.com/YuHvLURJ))

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-plugins</artifactId>
    <version>3.24.0-02</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

the build fails and returns the following error-message:

> The 'sonar.branch' parameter is no longer supported. You should stop
> using it. Branch analysis is available in Developer Edition and above.

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with git since I have not used branches nor does deleting git change anything.

Output, when using the command with full debug logging: [dump](https://pastebin.com/YuHvLURJ)

So how can I tell sonar to exclude the parent?

I'm a little overwhelmed.

Comment: Check the "effective pom" in Eclipse, u should find the "sonar.branch" property

Comment: I am going to do so once im on that project again, thank you for your input! Have a nice day :)

Comment: I haven't found any solution though, you can't "unset" this parent property.